# Materialize CSS FormSelect how to get second of letter when pressing keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am using materializeCSS on a web page with Jquery. I have a select box with lots of options. Normally with a select box I can price a letter multiple times to cycle through the options that start with that letter. When using materialize FormSelect though, I cannot do that. I press the letter once and it correctly takes me to the first entry of that letter. When I press it a second time though it leaves me there. I could use the down arrow, however in my case it is a list of countries with USA at the top since most customers are in the USA. If they happen to live in the United Kingdom though I would expect they could just press U, U to get there but they can't. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) in place of a select, which brings up a list of available options based on keypress. This is the markup from the documentation:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is a javascript component that needs initialising with, and when you initialise you can pass the data required:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
      data: {
        "United Kingdom": null,
        "USA": null,
        "Uruguay": null
      },
    });

  });
```

FYI, the null is an optional image src - so in your example you could maybe include the country flag:

```
"USA": '../img/usa.svg'
```

There are a number of other useful options you can pass - set how many characters trigger the dropdown, run a function when an option is selected, limit the number of options shown at once etc.

https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

Working demo Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/YzXdePM).